# How to predict multiple attributes using XGboost in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

I have a dataset with three input variables: lat, lon and angle. I would like to predict the same number of attributes, however, it only predicts the first attribute.

This is my code:

```
dat = np.array(gt2[['lat','lng']]/100000000)
dat=np.concatenate((dat,gt2[['angle']]),axis=1)

for num in range(10,101):
    raw= dat[0:num]
    X = raw[:-1]
    y = raw[1:]    
    xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor()
    dist=[]
    for i in range (0,10):     
        xg_reg.fit(X,y)  # training
        pred = xg_reg.predict([dat[(num-1)+i]])
        print(pred)       
        dst=hs.haversine(( pred[0,0] , pred[0,1] ),( dat[num+i,0] , dat[num+i,1] ), unit=Unit.METERS)   
        dist.append(dst)
        X = np.append(X, pred, axis=0)    
        y = np.append(y, pred, axis=0)        
    if ((dist[0]<dist[1])and(dist[1]<dist[2])and(dist[2]<dist[3])and(dist[3]<dist[4])and(dist[4]<dist[5])and(dist[0]<1)and(dist[1]<1)and(dist[2]<1)and(dist[3]<1)and(dist[4]<1)):
        print(num)
        print('1', dist[0],'2', dist[1],'3', dist[2],'4', dist[3],'5', dist[4])
```

The content of pred is:

```
array([41.319782], dtype=float32)
```

and the content of dat[(num-1)+i]:

```
array([ 41.32287833,   2.01513931, 133.2584301 ])
```

Any idea?

Update

I've tried using a single value to use as train and label, below the example:

The dataframe is the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    14215279993634829673
1    14215279993634774575
2    14215279993657262886
3    14215279993655650232
4    14215279993656041129
5    14215279993653034890
6    14215279993663569327
7    14215279993664053186
8    14215279993308738063
9    14215279993308129682
Name: gh, dtype: uint64
```

However, it fails in the fit function with this error:

```
XGBoostError: [18:23:06] /workspace/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:65: Check failed: preds.Size() == info.labels_.Size() (1 vs. 9) : labels are not correctly providedpreds.size=1, label.size=9
Stack trace:
```

Comment: think you gonna need two model for that whether you are solving classification or regression

Comment: @PatrickCharronMorneau I've updated the solution with a single attribute but still an error

Comment: Where do you do your [training](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_intro.html#training)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs you're right, I've forgotten to add here the ''xg_reg.fit(X,y) ''